# Setup squid3 proxy server on linux server with 2 ethernet ports

Tags: squid, ethernet

I need to setup squid3 proxy server on my linux machine with 2 ethernet ports(eth0 and eth1). eth0 has an IP address of 192.168.1.2 assigned by a router which provides internet to the system. eth1 is connected to a switch. I need squid3 to serve the switch through eth1. How should I configure eth1? I don't need the configurations for squid3. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a transparent proxy, then you don't need to bother giving eth1 an address. All the traffic can be handled by eth0.

If you do need a transparent proxy, you have two options here.

### Option 1: Bridge it

Configure both Ethernet faces into a bridge group, and then use iptables to handle the intercept. You assign the virtual bridge interface an IP address.

### Option 2: Route it

Configure your Squid server as a router. Install dhcp on it to ensure the rest of your network can get addresses. Then use iptables to handle the intercept.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please elaborate the second option?

Comment: @nitish Option 1 is actually a lot easier to set up, but I don't know how big of a network you're working with.

Comment: Ok. Can you please tell me how to do it? Its a small network with less than 20 computers.